# Backing up and restoring all databases in MySQL on linux

Tags: mysql, backup, linux, mysqldump

I plan to dump all databases on one computer and restore them on another using the following 2 commands:-

```
mysqldump -u username -p --all-databases > dump.sql

mysql -u username -p < dump.sql
```

My query is : will the second command overwrite an existing table with the same name as on the first computer ? Also, will the second command delete all tables which are NOT there on the first computer?

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact syntax used varies depending on what version of MySQL you are using, but the basic version of mysqldump (without any other options) you are using will run:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `test` /;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`;
CREATE TABLE `test1` (. . .
```

You can check this if you are concerned, before running the second statement, simply look in the file dump.sql (it is just a text file) and you can see clearly what queries it will run.

So to answer your questions:

> will the second command overwrite an existing table with the same name as on the first computer ?

Yes it will

> will the second command delete all tables which are NOT there on the first computer?

No it won't

You can get a full list of the options available from: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary

Comment: Many thanks. A related query. Suppose I have dumped only ONE database (mydb1)  by doing, mysqldump -u root -p --databases mydb1  > mydb1.sql, then we can do mysql -u root -p  < mydb1.sql on a new system. Some websites suggest that we first create an empty database with the same name(mydb1) prior to this. See for example this (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-backup-restore-a-mysql-database) I don't think that is needed. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct, because you used `--databases` it includes the `CREATE DATABASE mydb1` statement. In the example you link to, they omit the `--databases` option, in which case you need to create the new database first, and tell the second command (import) which database to use.

Comment: Query  : Are the following 2 the same?  mysql -u root -p --database=mydb < abc.sql vs mysql -u root -p mydb < abc.sql ? I think the 1st does not need the full path name, while the 2nd needs the full path name. How can I determine the full path for the second option ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are both basically the same, and will both need the full path to the file. The path will be wherever the mysqldump script puts the file. e.g. if you dump it to /tmp you would also load it from /tmp

Comment: You can of course combine the two `mysqldump -hxxx -P3306 -uroot -pxxxx [options] | mysql -hxxx -P3306 -uroot -pxxxx`. This means you don't need to worry about saving the file in the first place.

Comment: My apologies, I meant the path to the database. How can I find the path to the database ? The above link,once again,(https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-backup-restore-a-mysql-database) says The [database_name] is the path and filename of the database. I think if we use mysql -u root -p --database=mydb < abc.sql then we don't need the full path to the database, while mysql -u root -p mydb < abc.sql will need the full path to mydb.

Comment: I think that is a mistake on that link. I think the 'path' they refer to is for the filename.  As far as I know, you shouldn't need to provide a path to the database name, as that will be resolved automatically by the login details.